# Remote connecting to Asterisk mysql database from internet issue

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-5.1

I can connect to Asterisk MySQL database (`asteriskcdrdb`) and everything is okay. Asterisk server located in my LAN network. I can to connect to this database from my computer with Mysql client application.

Now I want to connect this database from another server that put on internet hosting. I set port forward on ADSL modem for connect to this database, but I can't connect and get this error:

```
[08S01]
    Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was ۰ milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.
```

I checked port forward configuration and everything is okay because I have another Mysql database on windows that work. Also I run `service iptables stop` on Asterisk server, but I get error.

What should I do?
Do you have any suggestion for my issue?

Thanks

Comment: The problem can be with "another server that put on internet hosting".  Does "internet hosting" equal "the cloud"?  First try from another system over which you have full control.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, I get a windows server that located on DigitalOcean and install a Mysql client to connect to mysql server that located on local area network. On local area network I have a modem with static IP address that access from internet.

Comment: Let me put it differently: can another system access your database via the internet?  Also, as you say another database is accessible, is the Asterisk DB listening on a different port?  Are both ports forwarded by your modem?  What is the error when you fail to stop iptables?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, Now I can connect to Asterisk DB from local network. For port forward test, I install mysql DB on a computer on local network and set port forward o modem ad every things is okay. both port forward on same modem. When I stop iptables, I didn't get error.

Comment: You say in your question: "Also I run service iptables stop on Asterisk server, but I get error.".   Do you know if tha Asterisk DB is listening on a TCP port, and which one?  The local connection can be via a socket.  Do you have "nmap" on the hosted system?

Answer (score 0):

Use secure SSL over VPN.  *Do not expose your telephone system to foreign and domestic hackers via the unsecured Internet!*